# How to create a range between series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does anyone have an idea how to optimize the series display by adding range between series when there is no value like the picture below.

[image]

For exemple between 3500MW  and 6500MW there is no value so how to do to in order to compact the series display like in the picture

thank alot for your help : )

Comment: Hey there, have you play around with https://d3js.org/ ? I think you can achieve that with it :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your response but the probleme is that we have to use highcharts for the project !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [yAxis.breaks](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks)

```
yAxis: {
    lineColor: 'black',
    lineWidth: 2,
    title: false,
    tickInterval: 100,
    breaks: [{
        from: 500,
        to: 3000
    }],
    events: {
        pointBreak: pointBreakColumn
    }
},
```

`breaks` defines where you would like the breaks to occur in the axis. The `pointBreak` event allows you to add special styling at the break points (for example, your zigzag line in the image).

Answer (score 0):

I Have tried using yAxis with type: 'logarithmic'? significantly reduce gap between far values.
Demo: [https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vj83L76q/]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: 'line'
},`enter code here`
yAxis: {
type: 'logarithmic'
},
series: [{
data: [100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 7000, 20000]
}]